# Where can I find information about cmusphinx framework?

Tags: java, android, cmusphinx

Where can I find information or source code of Android sphinx framework? I need to make a report about speech recognition technology, especially sphinx framework, how does it works, about optimization of it and etc.

Comment: A brief google search brings up a plethora of sources.

Comment: Maybe you could have found this yourself: http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/

Comment: Thanks, guys, I searched it for an hour, but don't find anything.

Comment: You can ask on cmusphinx forums too https://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/discussion/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the following publication about Pocketsphinx

https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~awb/papers/ICASSP2006/0100185.pdf

You can learn about Android from the corresponding wiki page

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid

For more in-depth review of speech recognition algorithms used in Pocketsphinx you can check the following thesis

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.72.3560